# the unity gives me a error when i put a null value into an input field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm relatively new to C# with unity and I've been making a number guessing game to learn. When I've been testing it I've input a null value into the input field where it breaks.

*something to note is that string and floating point data types are unable to be typed. thanks for any help :)*

---

I've tried making a nested if statement on top where it checks if the value is null and if it is it will tell the user to try again, but to no avail. Here's the code with some commenting below

```cs
//random number variable
public int randomNum;

//for answers really big or really small
private int randomNumSmall;
private int randomNumBig;

//user input
public InputField userInput;

void Start()
{
   //the math or the small and big numbers
   randomNumSmall = randomNum - 10;
   randomNumBig = randomNum + 10;
}

void Update()
{
}

public void OnButtonClick() //button click is what happens when the button is clicked
{
    //the user input being but into a string variable for storage
    string userInputValue = userInput.text;

    //converting the string to an int
    int answer = int.Parse(userInputValue);

    //first if statetment that supposed to check if its null or not
    if (userInputValue != "")
    {

        //logic for all possible responces with numbers
        if (answer < randomNum)
        {
            if (answer < randomNumSmall)
            {
                Debug.Log("Way too Low!");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Too low!");
            }
        }
        else if (answer > randomNum)
        {
            if (answer > randomNumBig)
            {
                Debug.Log("Way too high!");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Too high!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("You are correct!");
        }
    }
    //this else statement is supposed to redirect the user when inputting nothing
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Please write down a number");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error, what isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Verpous commented, please do provide an error when asking questions. Without one it can be troublesome to help you.

From looking at you code, I'm guessing it fails when you're trying to convert your string to an int `int answer = int.Parse(userInputValue);`. If you don't enter anything in your input-field the text will be empty and the `Parse` method will throw an exception. Instead, it is recommended to use the `TryParse` method which will return a boolean which indicates whether or not the parsing was a success. The converted int will be returned to you via the `out` parameter.

For reference: [MSDN Int64.TryParse docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64.tryparse?view=net-7.0)

Comment: oh ok ill keep tha in mind for the future, here's the error code:               
                                                                                                                  
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException (System.Boolean overflow, System.String overflowResourceKey) (at <75633565436c42f0a6426b33f0132ade>:0)
System.Number.ParseInt32

Comment: I thought it could be something like that but I was unable to put it in the correct way. how would I be able to do that?

Comment: If you visit the docs I linked in my answer, there's a code snippet that shows you how it can be done. But basically `bool success = int.TryParse(yourStringVariable, out int theIntResult);`. If `success` is true, `theIntResult` will contain the parsed value. If `success` is false, `theIntResult` will be 0.

Comment: it worked! thankyou for the help :) here's what I did:                                                                        
     **string userInputValue = userInput.text;


        bool success = int.TryParse(userInputValue, out int answer);**

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that the empty string is not null, it is the string consisting of 0 characters. To test both you would normally use the static function `string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)`. However, the input will not become null in your example, but you need to test for empty string before you parse it, it doesn't make sense to do it after. So you would do:

```cs
// first if statement that is supposed to check if it's empty or not
if (userInputValue != "")
{
    // converting the string to an int
    int answer = int.Parse(userInputValue);
    ...
}
```

Your code still won't work because you cannot be sure the input parses to a string, so you could use `int.TryParse` as the other answer suggests.

Remember to assign a value to RandomNum somewhere.

To use TryParse you could do the following:

```cs
//the user input being but into a string variable for storage
string userInputValue = userInput.text;

// trying to convert the string to an int
bool isInteger = int.TryParse(userInputValue, out int answer);
if (isInteger)
{
    // logic for all possible responses with numbers
    // you can safely use the answer variable here
    ...
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Please enter an integer number");
}
```

Comment: how could I do the TryParse in my code?